# How to open Creo Viewer in form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to open a existing executable application (PTC CREO VIEWER) and embed it into my application. I am using this code:

```
#Region "EMBADED PROGRAM"
Declare Auto Function SetParent Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hWndNewParent As IntPtr) As Integer
Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer
Declare Auto Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nIndex As Integer) As Integer
Declare Auto Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal nIndex As Integer, ByVal dwNewLong As Integer) As Integer
Declare Auto Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As IntPtr, ByVal X As Integer, ByVal Y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal uFlags As Integer) As Boolean

Private Const WM_SYSCOMMAND As Integer = 274
Private Const SC_MAXIMIZE As Integer = 61488
Private Const SC_MINIMIZE As Integer = 61472 ' &HF020

Private appProc As Process
Private winProc As Process

Public Sub LoadApp(filename As String, arguments As String)
    Try
        appProc = New Process()
        appProc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
        appProc.StartInfo.FileName = filename
        If arguments <> "" Then
            appProc.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments
        End If
        Dim isStartOK As Boolean = appProc.Start()
        Dim processName As String = appProc.ProcessName
        appProc.Refresh()
        Dim isWaitOk As Boolean = appProc.WaitForInputIdle(5000)
        appProc.Refresh()
        If Not isWaitOk Then
            MsgBox("WaitForInputIdle Not ok")
            Return
        End If
        Thread.Sleep(500)
        Dim processes As Process() = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(processName) ' IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(program))
        Console.WriteLine(processes.Length)
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
        For Each p As Process In processes
            If p.MainWindowHandle <> 0 Then
                winProc = p
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If (winProc.MainWindowHandle = 0) Then
            MsgBox("winProc.MainWindowHandle = 0")
            Return
        End If
        Thread.Sleep(500)
        SetParent(winProc.MainWindowHandle, Panel1.Handle)
        Thread.Sleep(100)
        SendMessage(winProc.MainWindowHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0)
        Me.BringToFront()

        'MakeExternalWindowBorderless(winProc.MainWindowHandle)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
    End Try
End Sub

Public Sub CloseApp()
    Try
        If Not IsNothing(winProc) Then
            winProc.CloseMainWindow()
            winProc.Close()
        End If
        If Not IsNothing(appProc) Then
            appProc.CloseMainWindow()
            appProc.Close()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
End Sub
#End Region
```

I can get apps like notepad.exe or mspaint.exe to run in panel of my application, but this is not working for Creo Viewer or Chrome either. 
The `Dim isWaitOk As Boolean = appProc.WaitForInputIdle(5000)` always returns false (with creo viewer), I tried to set more timeout but it is still not working. I have also tried `appProc.Refresh()` in `while` loop but nothing. I am not getting the `MainWindowHandle` of a embedded app.

Do someone know any other way to open PTC Creo Viewer Express in windows forms application (VB.NET)?

Comment: what do you get in `processName` variable.

Comment: This: `If Not IsNothing(winProc) Then` should rather be: `If winProc IsNot Nothing Then`.

Comment: @AliAshraf, I get pvexpress in variable processName. This is the name of .exe file of Creo Viewer (full path example: C:\Program Files\PTC\Creo 4.1\View Express\bin\pvexpress.exe)

Comment: @VisualVincent, I will change that but this is not the solution.

Comment: Never said it'd be either, but it is better quality code. See: http://blog.reneorban.com/2011/12/vbnet-isnothing-vs-is-nothing.html